# Introduce loading time delay before getting the URL in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I need to web-scrape through a number of pages. Given that there are many pages, I first write down the html files in my external HD and then process them.

The problem is that when I try to get the URL I always download the same page, because the website waits half a second to display the new page.

The code is as follows

```
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)
library(XML)

for(i in 1:numberPages){
  # Generate the unique URL for each page 
  url <- str_c('https://www..../#{"page":"', i, '"}')


  # Download the page
  bill.result <- try(getURL(url))
  while(class(bill.result)=="try-error"){ # if class()==error, retry to get the url after 1 sec
    cat("Page irresponsive - trying again")
    Sys.sleep(1)
    bill.result <- try(getURL(url))
  }

  # Write the page to local hard drive
  result <- try(write(bill.result, str_c(new_folder, "/page", i, ".html")))

  while(class(result)=="try-error"){ # if class()==error, retry to write after 2 min
    cat("I will sleep if network is down")
    Sys.sleep(120)
    result <- try(write(bill.result, str_c(new_folder, "/page", i, ".html")))
  }

  # Print progress of download
  cat(i, "\n")
}
```

I have searched and haven´t found an option that would wait, say, 1 second before *getting* the URL. Without this wait time, I always download the same page, no matter where in the loop I am. I know this because when I change the url address in my browser the page is the same for 1 second, and then it changes to the page I wanted in the first place.

Comment: What does `www....` go to? My experience on SO is that those who mask URLs either are scraping an internal site (but your problem is not indicative of that since you could work with your admins to accommodate you) or are attempting to violate terms of services. There are, of course, edge cases of legitimacy. There are a few of us who would just like to be sure we're not enabling content theft.

Comment: I am trying to scrape apartment prices in Brazil, in order to have a sense of neighborhood income in selected cities. The website is the following https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/ 
It does not look like I am violating any terms of service, at least I hope I am not.

Comment: Not that hard to discern from https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/informacao?opcao=termouso ; there are folks on SO who are ambivalent about IP theft so you may still get folks to assist.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. Thank you for the heads up, though.